# Natural language processing with elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, named-entity-recognition, data-extraction

I wanted to integrate search functionality in my website.

I am using elastic search for it, If user searches "Maruti suzkuki under 2 lac" then it has to search cars having brand name "Maruti Suzuki" and price under [2 lac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system).
How can I achieve this?

Types of searches

1. maruti suzuki under 2 lac
2. maruti suzuki 20000km driven
3. cars 2015 year model 
   etc.

ES version 5.4

Comment: I know I wanted to use named entity recognition. I want to know how could I achieve this using named entity recognition.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-opennlp-plugin

Comment: It is depricated.

Comment: Sorry, this is the right link: https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-ingest-opennlp

Comment: It looks good. Can I define my own entities (mysql column name) 
like "maruti suzuki" is make_name.

Comment: @Val It is incompatible  with elasticsearch version 5.4.0

Comment: Nowhere in your question it was stated that you're using ES 5.4 :-)

Comment: Sorry for it, I am using ES 5.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145177/discussion-between-ijaj-mulani-and-val).

Comment: @Val Can you please help me in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896920/natural-language-processing-using-elasticsearch-and-google-cloud-api